# How to open single "Get Info window" for several/multiple files/dirs?

Tags: swift, macos, finder, nspasteboard

I have a code:

```
func openGetInfoWnd(for urls: [URL]) {
    let pBoard = NSPasteboard(name: NSPasteboard.Name(rawValue: "pasteBoard_\(UUID().uuidString )") )
    
    pBoard.writeObjects(urls as [NSPasteboardWriting])
    
    NSPerformService("Finder/Show Info", pBoard)
}
```

this code opens multiple windows of Finder's "Get Info"

> like it displays on Cmd + I hotkey

How can I open single one window ("Show Inspector" / "Get Info" / "Multiple Item Info") for multiple local urls?

> Like it displayed on Cmd + Option + I press in Finder

[image]

PS: code: `NSPerformService("Finder/Show Inspector", pBoard)` ofc does not work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried many ways, you are right, NSPerformService is very limited, and cannot achieve it. And I also tried `Apple Script's approach`:

```
tell application "Finder" to open information window of file aFile
```

But that only works for the single file and there is no open "multiple information window" thing in Finder.

Luckily, your keyboard shortcuts remind me that I can **simulate the file selection and keyboard keydown events**.

So I believe below apple script can help you:

```
set fileList to {POSIX file "/Users/0x67/Downloads/new.html", POSIX file "/Users/0x67/Pictures/tt/00003-771884301.png"}

tell application "Finder"
    activate
    set selection to fileList
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "i" using {command down, option down}
    end tell
end tell
```

[image]

I think you can call this create this apple script in Swift and call it.

Here is a useful link to [call it in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163433/can-you-execute-an-applescript-script-from-a-swift-application):

Comment: tried to call this script on my PC with correct local paths and got an error: `NSAppleScriptErrorMessage:Finder got an error: Application isn’t running.; NSAppleScriptErrorRange:NSRange: {240, 8}; NSAppleScriptErrorBriefMessage:Application isn’t running.; NSAppleScriptErrorNumber:-600; NSAppleScriptErrorAppName:Finder;`

Comment: same script can be executed from "Script editor" without any issues, but from code this errod displayed

Answer (score 2):

`NSAppleScriptErrorNumber: -600` is a sandbox issue, to fix it (tested in Xcode 14.3):

1. Go to **[Your Project] > [Your Target] > Signing & Capabilities**.
2. Delete **App Sandbox**.
3. Under **Hardened Runtime** (add the capability first by clicking <kbd>+ Capability</kbd> if necessary), check "Apple Events".
4. Add `NSAppleEventsUsageDescription` to your `Info.plist`.

Using [@kakaiikaka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76200542/10446972),

```swift
func openGetInfoWnd(for urls: [URL]) {
    let fileList = urls.map { "POSIX file \"\($0.absoluteString)\"" }
    let source = """
set fileList to {\(fileList.joined(separator: ", "))}
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    set selection to fileList
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "i" using {command down, option down}
    end tell
end tell
"""
    let appleScript = NSAppleScript(source: source)!
    var error: NSDictionary?
    appleScript.executeAndReturnError(&error)
    
    // ...
}
```

Rebuild your app (clean build + run) and it should now ask for permissions to send keystrokes to Finder. You'll likely see these pop-ups:

- Asking for permission to access the directories (the urls with which the function is invoked).
- Asking for permission to control "Finder" and "System Events" (separate pop-ups with the message you specified for the key `NSAppleEventsUsageDescription`).
- Asking for Accessibility Access (you'll have to go to **System Settings > Privacy & Security > Accessibility** to grant access).

Now everything should work! :)

P.S. If you get a message saying *"This method should not be called on the main thread as it may lead to UI unresponsiveness."*, just do:

```swift
DispatchQueue(label: "AppleScript").async {
    // execute the applescript here instead...
}
```

(you can also set `qos = .background` if you want, but either way should work)

Comment: thanks, I believe we did it together!

Comment: @kakaiikaka yay! thanks to you! ;)

Comment: Xcode Version 14.3 (14E222b) - there is no capability Apple Events. | NSAppleEventsUsageDescription - already in plist | also there is no `DispatchQueue(name:) `, but there is `DispatchQueue(label: )` (I have fixed your answer at this point). Are you using some old XCode?

Comment: The capability you are looking for is "Hardened Runtime" and there is an option called "Apple Events" under that. Sorry for the confusion on `DispatchQueue(label:)`, it was a typo.

Comment: Note: if the inspector window is open then Command-Option-i will close it.